# Is there any Excel Formula for comparing 2 columns for containing data and counting their occurrence?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

**Hello everybody**.
I ran into some problems when comparing data in columns in **Excel / G-Sheets**.
I tried to compare 2 columns with **company names** using the standard formula "**=countif (A:A, B2)**", where column **"A"** containing the names of the companies I am looking for **(acceptable)** and column **"B"** containing the names of companies that should match with company names in column **"A"**.
**For example**, in column **"A"** there is a cell with the name of the company **"Apple"**, and if in column **"B"** there is no cell with **"Apple"**, it should return **"0"**, but if on the contrary, it should return **"1", "2", etc**.
But the problem is if a cell with “**Apple Inc.**” appears in column **"B"** it will return **“0”**, although this is the same company. Therefore, I am trying to find a formula where I can count cells not with an exact match, but if it even contains part of the value.
For example, if in column A we have a cell with value **"Apple"**, if in column B we have **"Apple Inc."**, **"GTX Apple"**, **"The Apple"** values formula must return **"3"**.
I found some using "*" sign in countif formula, but it does not work as I want. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Some `regular expresions` could help, or you could use `VLOOKUP`. It's defined by: `=VLOOKUP(What you want to look up, where you want to look for it, the column number in the range containing the value to return, return an Approximate or Exact match – indicated as 1/TRUE, or 0/FALSE).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,"*" & A2 & "*")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but now i have another problem that should be solved. Can you check it?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777715/is-there-any-excel-g-sheets-formula-for-comparing-2-columns-for-containing-data