# Partial match in excel, multiple values in match criteria to match against list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I have a list of ID's that have multiple countries in a string.

[image]

```
ID  Countries
1   DK, US
2   PL, UK
3   CN, RU, DE
4   SE, FI
5   US, FI, DE
6   DK
```

Then I have a list I want to check if any country exist in this list.

[image]

```
Country Country Code
Sweden  SE
Denmark DK
Finland FI
```

So for example, `DK, US` should return `TRUE` since DK exist in Sheet1 list.

I have tried:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A;MATCH("*"&Sheet2!B2&"*";Sheet1!B:B;0))
```

But this dosn't work since I'm trying to match `DK, US` against `DK` or `SE`.

---

I would like to avoid using VBA or splitting the countries to separate columns. I think help/dummy columns is totally fine but not optimal

Comment: I would have put each country code in a separate column for that id or even multiple id entries 1 for each country then searched a range of cells.

Comment: I would like to avoid that if possible (it's extraction from database). 75k rows and in some cells I have 10-20 countries. It will become heavy and messy in this already large workbook :(.

Comment: Notable similarities to (but not a duplicate of) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777715/formula-for-comparing-2-columns-for-containing-data-and-counting-their-occurence/62778597)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")=TRANSPOSE(F$2:F$4)))>0
```

Or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(", "&$F$2:$F$4&", ",", "&B2&", ")))>0
```

Drag down.

Comment: This is so amazing!!! I wish I could give you a double-accept :)!!! Thank you, saves a lot of time!! :)

Comment: @Wizhi, glad it helped. These sort of (well formulated) questions are fun to work on (but been done on SO before I'm sure). If you are interested in what `FILTERXML` can do for you, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194)