# Macro to find specific words in a list of string expressions

Tags: excel, vba

What I am attempting to do is reference one column to find a keyword in another column.  For example:

[image: Simplified Example]

What I will need to search is thousands of cells in column C to hundreds in Column A.  When a string is found in A from C, I would like it to Highlight.

In this case after the Macro is ran the only cells that would be highlighted would be "Bird Cat" and "The Snake".  What I have got so far is the following:

```
Sub Test()

Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Find(What:="Bird", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=x1Formulas2, _
        LookAt:=x1Part, SearchOrder:=x1ByRows, SearchDirection:=x1Next, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormulas:=False).Activate
    Selection.Style = "Good"
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate

    
End Sub
```

At one point I did have a Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)...Loop in the code but I was thinking that would not work.

I am still new to coding in VBA so any input in general would be welcomed.

Comment: You have a bunch of `x1` prefixes there instead of `xl`

Comment: Is there a reason for not just using Conditional Formatting to do this without VBA?  ([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777715/formula-for-comparing-2-columns-for-containing-data-and-counting-their-occurence/))

Comment: What if you've got "cake" in C and "pancake" in A?

Comment: What if you've got "cake" in C and "pancake" in A?

I am not worried about this.  in the actual data set column A would be "Provisioning Item for [userID] for the program" and column c would be [userID].  It would be a letter then a string of 5 numbers.  I am trying to search any tickets I may have vs the system to see who may be provisioned.

Answer (score 1):

This code employs Find and FindNext to look for a single word and mark all cells where it was found.

```
Sub MarkMatches(ByVal Crit As String)
    ' 085

    Dim Rng         As Range                ' range to search
    Dim Fnd         As Range                ' cell where match was found
    Dim FirstFnd    As Long                 ' row where a match was first found
    Dim Arr         As Variant              ' Rng.Value (for execution speed)
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")               ' change to suit
        ' search in column A, starting from row 1
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    With Rng
        Arr = .Value
        .Interior.Pattern = xlNone          ' clear existing colouring
        Set Fnd = .Find(Crit, .Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        xlValues, xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
            FirstFnd = Fnd.Row
            Do
                ' "1" refers to column A here:-
                Arr(Fnd.Row, 1) = " " & Arr(Fnd.Row, 1) & " "
                ' exclude partial matches, like "catalog" matching "cat"
                If InStr(1, Arr(Fnd.Row, 1), " " & Crit & " ", vbTextCompare) Then
                    Fnd.Interior.Color = vbYellow       ' mark found match
                End If
                Set Fnd = .FindNext(Fnd)
                If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While Fnd.Row > FirstFnd
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You can call the above sub with a procedure like the one given below.

```
Sub Macro1()
    MarkMatches "bird"
End Sub
```

Instead of specifying the word you might specify a cell reference, like 'MarkMatches(Cells(2, "A").Value'. If you wish to search for a list of words you could place this call in a loop but you would first need to resolve how to differentiate between words marked because they match one criterion or another.

The procedure MarkMatches contains the line `Rng.Interior.Pattern = xlNone` which removes all previous highlights. The action of this line could be moved to the calling procedure but your present question doesn't say enough about your intentions to implement a better strategy.

Comment: I just put this above, but n the actual data set column A would be "Provisioning Item for [userID] for the program" and column c would be [userID]. It would be a letter then a string of 5 numbers. What I did was pull all of the UserID from the system.  I then took all the ID's and put them into an Excel document with the Ticket numbers/ Summary from my ServiceNow tickets for that system.I have about 10,000 tickets to go through across 15 different systems.  I can sort the data to single out the system and pull all active users on said system, but beyond that I am not able to automate

Comment: Kinda shifting the goal posts, are we? :-) I don't think your analogy was so bad. Therefore my code is useful. You can enter a userID and get all the associated ticket numbers highlighted. Perhaps you want to extend this to create a filtered list but that would be the subject of another question here on the forum, as would be the question of how to automate the process further. You would need to find room to describe the process, which we don't have here.